# Search for multiline String in a text file

Tags: java, string, file, bufferedreader, multiline

I have a text file from which i am trying to search for a String which has multiple lines. A single string i am able to search but i need multi line string to be searched.

I have tried to search for single line which is working fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
  File f1=new File("D:\\Test\\test.txt"); 
  String[] words=null;  
  FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);  
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
  String s;     
  String input="line one"; 

  // here i want to search for multilines as single string like 
  //   String input ="line one"+
  //                 "line two";

  int count=0;   
  while((s=br.readLine())!=null)   
  {
    words=s.split("\n");  
    for (String word : words) 
    {
      if (word.equals(input))   
      {
        count++;    
      }
    }
  }

  if(count!=0) 
  {
    System.out.println("The given String "+input+ " is present for "+count+ " times ");
  }
  else
  {
    System.out.println("The given word is not present in the file");
  }
  fr.close();
}
```

And below are the file contents.

```
line one  
line two  
line three  
line four
```

Comment: what if two lines are not adjacent?

Comment: then its not require to search. only when lines are adjacent it should search.

Comment: `line one  
line two  
line three  
line four` are these your search values you read from the file or you have search values in different place and search inside the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `StringBuilder` for that, read every line from file and append them to `StringBuilder` with `lineSeparator`

```
StringBuilder lineInFile = new StringBuilder();

while((s=br.readLine()) != null){
  lineInFile.append(s).append(System.lineSeparator());
}
```

Now check the `searchString` in `lineInFile` by using `contains`

```
StringBuilder searchString = new StringBuilder();

builder1.append("line one");
builder1.append(System.lineSeparator());
builder1.append("line two");

System.out.println(lineInFile.toString().contains(searchString));
```

Comment: i am searching in a text file and number of lines are not fixed, it can be of multiple lines as well. In that case do you think it would be feasible ?

Comment: yes look at my code until you don't have all lines from file how can you check lines existed in are not? @Janny

Comment: I got your point but in the real application i am not suppose to hard code the  values like "line one", "line two" and all. Any idea in that case how it would help ?

Comment: they you need to read them from somewhere right? how to get the input line to search in file? @Janny

Comment: what  do you mean not sure? from somewhere you need to get content to search in file right? if you need to read it from another file, read that into another stringbuilder @Janny

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194655/discussion-between-janny-and-deadpool).

Answer (score 0):

More complicated solution from default C (code is based on code from book «The C programming language» )

```java
final String searchFor = "Ich reiß der Puppe den Kopf ab\n" +
        "Ja, ich reiß' ich der Puppe den Kopf ab";

int found = 0;

try {
    String fileContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(
        new File("puppe-text").toPath()
    ));

    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < fileContent.length(); i++) {
        for (k = i, j = 0; (fileContent.charAt(k++) == searchFor.charAt(j++)) && (j < searchFor.length());) {
            // nothig
        }

        if (j == searchFor.length()) {
            ++found;
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ignore) {}

System.out.println(found);
```

Comment: i am trying to do in java

Comment: @Janny it's java, but the solution taken from book of C

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just normalize all the lines in the file to one string variable and then just count the number of occurrences of the input in the file. I have used `Regex` to count the occurrences but can be done in any custom way you find suitable.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
        File f1=new File("test.txt"); 
        String[] words=null;  
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);  
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
        String s;     
        String input="line one line two"; 

        // here i want to search for multilines as single string like 
        //   String input ="line one"+
        //                 "line two";

        int count=0;
        String fileStr = "";
        while((s=br.readLine())!=null)   
        {
            // Normalizing the whole file to be stored in one single variable
            fileStr += s + " ";
        }

        // Now count the occurences
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(input);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(fileStr);
        while (m.find()) {
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println(count); 

        fr.close();
}
```

Use `StringBuilder` class for efficient string concatenation.

Comment: the files are too long, will that be a good idea to normalize into a single variable.

Comment: Yes that is definitely not a good idea. Instead of storing it in a `String` variable you could keep on appending with `StringBuilder` because `String` assignment is slow. The best way to determine whether it will work is to just run it and check. If loading everything in memory is a problem then there are edge cases I can think of which might pose problem.

Comment: Best approach is to use the easiest possible solution and then optimize it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Scanner.findWithinHorizon()

```
String pathToFile = "/home/user/lines.txt";
String s1 = "line two";
String s2 = "line three";

String pattern = String.join(System.lineSeparator(), s1, s2);

int count = 0;
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(pathToFile))) {
  while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String withinHorizon = scanner.findWithinHorizon(pattern, pattern.length());
    if (withinHorizon != null) {
      count++;
    } else {
      scanner.nextLine();
    }

  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: it is just one string not two. Single string contains multiple lines.

Comment: String.join(System.lineSeparator(), s1, s2) == "line two" + "\n" + "line three"

Answer (score -1):

Try This,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File f1 = new File("./src/test/test.txt");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String input = "line one";
    int count = 0;

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains(input)) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    if (count != 0) {
        System.out.println("The given String " + input + " is present for " + count + " times ");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The given word is not present in the file");
    }
    fr.close();
}
```

Comment: i want to search for multi line String input ="line one"+  "line two";

Comment: line one in first line, line two in second line.