# How to find missing words in a text file

Tags: java

I have two text files one with a long text and another with a short text (about 5-7 words) and I need to find the missing words from the file with the short text. The file with the short text looks like this : Tacos _ _ best things _ _ world

I readed the short file into a queue and the other file in a bufferedReader. Now I am going through the text and if the first word of the queue euquals the word in the text, I remove it from the queue and add it to another Queue. Then I will look, what the next word is and add if it equals a word in the queue. If yes, I want to add it to the queue and if not I want to look how far the next word in the queue is away from the current word. If it matches with te input from the queue I want to add the sentence to the output queue and print it out

My code currently looks like this:

````java
package Nr1;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class main1 {



    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        
        Queue<String> eingabe = new LinkedList<String>();
        Queue<String> ausgabe = new LinkedList<String>();

        //Für die Eingabe des Dateinamens in der Konsole
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Geben sie den Dateinamen ein:");
        String dateiname = br.readLine();

        //Datei wird eingelesen
        File file = new File("./assets/Aufgabe1/" + dateiname + ".txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        //String mit dem Inhalt der gestörten Datei
        String line = reader.readLine();

        //String wird in einzelne Wörter aufgeteilt und in die Queue eingefügt
        String[] words = line.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            eingabe.add(words[i]);
        }

        //Datei wird geschlossen
        reader.close();

        System.out.println(eingabe);

        //TODO in dem Text nach den Wörtern suchen und die Wörter in die Queue einfügen

        File tacoText = new File("TacoText.txt");
        String[] woerter = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tacoText));
        String s;
        int nextWord = 0;
        String input = eingabe.peek();
        int count = 0;

        while((s = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null && !eingabe.isEmpty()) {
            words = s.split(" ");

            for (String word : words) {
                String input2 = eingabe.peek();
                if (word.equals(input)) {
                    ausgabe.add(input);
                    eingabe.remove();
                    nextWord++;
                    input2 = eingabe.peek();
                    System.out.println(input2);
                    System.out.println(word);
                    System.out.println(eingabe.peek());
                }
                if(nextWord == 1) {
                    ausgabe.add(word);
                    eingabe.remove();
                    nextWord++;
                    input2 = eingabe.peek();
                    System.out.println(input2);
                    System.out.println(word);
                    System.out.println(eingabe.peek());
                }
                if(nextWord == 2 && word.equals(input2)) {
                    ausgabe.add(word);
                    eingabe.remove();
                    nextWord++;
                    input2 = eingabe.peek();
                    System.out.println(input2);
                    System.out.println(word);
                    System.out.println(eingabe.peek());
                }
                if(nextWord == 3 && word.equals(input2)) {
                    ausgabe.add(word);
                    eingabe.remove();
                    nextWord++;
                    input2 = eingabe.peek();
                    System.out.println(input2);
                    System.out.println(word);
                    System.out.println(eingabe.peek());
                }
                if(nextWord == 4 && word.equals(input2)) {
                    ausgabe.add(word);
                    eingabe.remove();
                    nextWord++;
                    input2 = eingabe.peek();
                    System.out.println(input2);
                    System.out.println(word);
                    System.out.println(eingabe.peek());
                }
                if(nextWord == 5 && word.equals(input2)) {
                    ausgabe.add(word);
                    eingabe.remove();
                    nextWord++;
                    input2 = eingabe.peek();
                    System.out.println(input2);
                    System.out.println(word);
                    System.out.println(eingabe.peek());
                }
                if(nextWord == 6 && word.equals(input2)) {
                    ausgabe.add(word);
                    eingabe.remove();
                    nextWord++;
                    input2 = eingabe.peek();
                    System.out.println(input2);
                    System.out.println(word);
                    System.out.println(eingabe.peek());
                }
                if(nextWord == 7 && word.equals(input2)) {
                    ausgabe.add(word);
                    if(!eingabe.isEmpty()) {
                        eingabe.remove();
                    }
                    nextWord++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(ausgabe);
    }
}```
````

Comment: the output in the Queue is always the same word

Answer (score 1):

I would turn the short text into a regular expression pattern, and parse the large text with that regular expression.
But, I am assuming this is a homework assignment (make sure you add that tag to the question) and you have not been taught regular expressions yet.

So, I'll just give some tips on improving your current approach.
At first glance, the direct cause that it fails, is likely because you have used `if` instead of `else if` in the main body of the loop. That means that all the `if`s are evaluated in sequence for each word.

You don't test on `_` anywhere, so you will not find the missing words.

But the repeated `if`s with identical bodies are also a sign that you have an approach that is too rigid. I am sure that nothing in the assignment says that the short sentence must have 8 words, and your approach will fail any other sentence. Make sure that you have an approach that works more flexibly. Something like the following:

Keep an index into the pattern that keeps track of which word you are matching.
For each word in the input, compare it with the currently indexed word. If it matches, increase the index. If the indexed word is a `_` it always matches, remember the word it matches to and increase the index. If the indexed word does not match, reset the index to 0, and skip to the next line in the input.
If the index reaches the length of the pattern, output the remembered words and finish.

Another tip that will help you in the future: make sure all variable names, and all comments are in English. Only use a local language for texts that are presented to the user.

Comment: This isn´t homework task. I want to learn something new and found this task online. I tried it but can´t complete it so I posted it here

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fits your task, but you can code this much easier using regex:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    
  String text = "foo bar Tacos are the best things in the world bar";
  String foo="Tacos _ _ best things _ _ world";
  
  String words[] = foo.split(" ");

  String regex = "";
  for ( String w : words ){
      if ( w.equals("_")){
          regex += "(\\w*)+ ";
      }else{
          regex += "(" + w + ")+ ";
      }
  }
  //  regex =>  (Tacos)+ (\w*)+ (\w*)+ (best)+ (things)+ (\w*)+ (\w*)+ (world)+ 

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    
  while (matcher.find()) {
       System.out.println("Full sentence: " + matcher.group(0));
       //  Full sentence:  Tacos are the best things in the world
  }      
}
```

Besides, going through the textfile line by line will not work if the sentence you search for is split over several lines.
Take a look at:  [Search for multiline String in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56511964/search-for-multiline-string-in-a-text-file)

Comment: Hi, it could be a good idea, but the text we have is about 1000 Characters long so I don´t know if I can do it this way. Is it possible to convert the text String into a file?

Comment: I looked it up and the text file has 25741 words in the file

Comment: Read your file into String as it is explained in the linked question.